# Access variables and their names from the current scope

Tags: vba

Is it possible to:

1. Access a list of all variables in a VBA runtime environment?
2. Access the name of a variable with VBA?

**Example:**

```
function v2S(str as string) as string
    For each variable in Variables
        dim I as integer
        for I = 1 to 10
            v2S = replace(v2S,"%" & variable.name & "%", variable.value)
        next
    next
end function
```

Example use case:

```
Dim skyColor as string
skyColor = "green"
Debug.Print v2S("The sky is %skyColor% today!")
```

There is an application I can send commands to via a com object and I wish to do something along the lines of:

```
Dim i a integer
for i = 1 to MI.Eval("numtables()")
    MI = GetObject(,"MapInfo.Application.x64")
    debug.print MI.Eval(v2S("tableinfo(%i%,1)")) ' Print name of table
next
```

The above looks much cleaner than:

```
Dim i a integer
for i = 1 to MI.Eval("numtables()")
    MI = GetObject(,"MapInfo.Application.x64")
    debug.print MI.Eval(v2S("tableinfo(" & i & ",1)")) ' Print name of table
next
```

But of course if it were possible I would want it to be general which may be difficult...

Comment: im guessing the locals/watchers windows arent sufficient?

Comment: The only way I know of to get a list of variables (apart from the locals window of course) is to search the code for keywords such as `Dim` and extract the names that way. Even so that wouldn't help you to accomplish what you're suggesting. This sounds like more of a code design issue because there shouldn't be a case where you would need to do this.

Comment: @Ben It's not a code design issue. There are many cases when a programmer needs to inject variables into strings. This is why languages such as ruby have [string interpolation](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html). In fact whenever you want to call another programming language from VBA you need to write the code in strings e.g. running SQL commands on a SQL database. It's also super handy for debugging!

Comment: VBA doesn't support any sort of reflection/introspection. VBA also lacks a concise string formatting (e.g., `print('some string {}'.format(some_variable)`) etc.

Comment: @Sancarn I agree that it has its uses, but when the language you use doesn't support such functionality (VBA for example) then it may be worth rethinking what you want to accomplish

Comment: @BenShelton Right I see where you're coming from! You're correct, there are much better ways to do what I'm trying to do, but sadly I have little choice in what language I choose. It must be easy to use for a non-programmer and must not include installing a foreign executable (that's IT group policy...). So I'm already pretty limited as to what I can do sadly...

Answer (score 0):

For my own use case [this is pretty good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31730589/6302131).

However it still isn't very readable. This is another option. It's more readable but also more cluttered:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Vars as object, myString as string
    set Vars = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")
    Vars.add "Var1","Val1"
    Vars.add "Var2","Val2"
    '...
    myString = r("Var1: #{Var1} and Var2: #{Var2}", Vars)
End Sub

function r(byval s as string, byval o as object) as string
    for each key in o.keys
        s = replace(s,"#{" & key & "}",o.item(key))
    next
    r = s
end function
```

I wish string interpolation functionality existed by default in VBA.