# ms-access run-time error 3075 extra ) in vbasql

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

#### Code

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT tblHS_area_fields.hsaf_id " _
& "FROM tblHS_area_fields " _
& "WHERE (((tblHS_area_fields.hs_area_id)=" & hs_area_id & ") AND ((tblHS_area_fields.hsf_id)=13))"


Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

#### Errors

The error when trying to run from a Form is:

```
Extra ) in query expression '(((tblHS_area_fields.hs_area_id)=" &
> hs_area_id & ") AND ((tblHS_area_fields.hsf_id)=13))'
```

Getting an error from immediate window:

```
Compile error: expected:  line number or label or statement or end of statement
```

All fields are numbers.

What is wrong with the VBA code and SQL statement?

Comment: what is "hs_area_id" ?  cast it to a string  Cstr(hs_area_id) and see what new error comes out.

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove all brackets in your sql:

```
strSQL = "SELECT tblHS_area_fields.hsaf_id " & _
"FROM tblHS_area_fields " & _
"WHERE tblHS_area_fields.hs_area_id = " & hs_area_id & " AND tblHS_area_fields.hsf_id = 13 "
```

In this case you don't need the brackets.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but I then get run-time error 3075: Syntax error (missing operator) in the same portion of the sql. Thanks

Comment: Do you have bound control for `hs_area_id` ? @Capnbigal

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment:
Next time, add a `Debug.Print strSql`, then create a query in SQL view, copy you SQL statement from the debug window (ctrl+G) and paste you statement there.
Or just paste it in Visual Studio...
You should then quickly see the issue(s)

Answer (score 0):

Consider to debug-print and log your SQL before executing: `Debug.print(strSQL)`.

#### Opening brackets must match closing ones

Some break-down helps recognizing and matching, correct is:

```
strSQL = "SELECT hsaf_id" _
& " FROM tblHS_area_fields" _
& " WHERE (" _
  & "( hs_area_id =" & hs_area_id & ")" _
  & " AND ( hsf_id = 13 )" _
& ")"
```

For SQL templates you could also use string replace function or string-templating with a custom-function. See [VBA string interpolation syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221349/vba-string-interpolation-syntax).